# Multiple Hypotheses in python

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, chi-square-test, pvalue

I want to write a method to test multiple hypotheses for a pair of schools (say TAMU and UT Austin). I want to consider all possible pairs of words (Research Thesis   Proposal   AI   Analytics), and test the hypothesis that the words counts differ significantly across the two schools, using the specified alpha (0.05) threshold.

Only need to conduct tests on words that have non-zero values for both schools. I.e., every row and column in the contingency table should `sum to >0`.

Finally, want to return a tuple with the

- The total number of tests conducted, and
- The number of significant tests.

Sample data frame:

| Names | Research | Thesis | Proposal | AI | Analytics Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TAMU | 54 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 5 |
| uiuc | 33 | 43 | 5 | 0 | 76 |
| USC | 4 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 21 |
| UT Austin | 22 | 31 | 0 | 0 | 55 |
| UCLA | 55 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 11 |

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
def school_term_hypotheses(filename,college1, college2, alpha):
   
   df=pd.read_csv(filename)
   df=df[(df['Name'] == college1) | (df['Name'] == college2)]
   df=df.loc[:, df.ne(0).all()]
   df=df.set_index('Unnamed: 0')
   #chi,p=chi2_contingency(df)[:2]
   #return(p)

school_term_hypotheses("test.csv", 'TAMU','UT Austin' 0.05)
```

I am clueless about what to do after getting a df with non-zero values. need some help figuring how do I test multiple hypotheses.

Comment: This is more of a statistics related query than data science related. It is better if you first search it on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and if you don't find your answer, then ask it there only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```py
from scipy import stats
def chi_squared_test(df,college1,college2,alpha):
    contingency_table = pd.crosstab(df.loc[college1,:],df.loc[college2,:])
    try:
        stat,p,dof,expected = stats.chi2_contingency(contingency_table)
    except:
        return None
    return p
```

Comment: 'the label [purdue.txt] is not in the [index]' bro

Comment: also this wont consider consider all possible pairs of words and return the total number of tests conducted